# In R, is it possible to define a function with an argument that is a function?

Tags: r

I would like to create a function with one of the arguments as what to pass into a function, but keep getting an error. Explicitly what I'm trying to do is:

```
myfunc <- function(f = function(x) dnorm(x, mean=1)){
                  area <- integrate(f, 0, 2)
                  print(area)
          }
```

Essentially, I would like to define the function to be used in the `integrate` function as an argument so I can control it globally. This doesn't work though, am I doing something very wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: what does "doesn't work" mean? What error are you getting? running `myfunc()` gives me 
`0.6826895 with absolute error < 7.6e-15`, which seems reasonable (you might want to `return(area)` rather than `print(area)` ...

Comment: Oh I see -- I am running `myfunc(f)`, which results in an error. Do you know why this results? I thought just writing `f` inside is sufficient?

Comment: @user1398057 - that is equivalent to `myfunc(f=f)` - if `f` isn't defined in your current working environment, you will get an `object 'f' not found` error

Comment: see `lapply` or `sapply` or `apply` and also `match.fun`

Comment: In terms of passing a function into another function, you can pass it in as a string, ie `f<-function(func = "dnorm")`, and then inside the function use `get(func)`

Comment: @aeongrail IIUC, the purpose of `match.fun` is to avoid exactly that, since `match.fun` won't match non-function objects in the namespace

Comment: Yep, that's true I just use the (probably) bad practise and use get anytime I have the name of something in a string!